# Mapping an enum to a string

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I am in the process of migrating some old legacy database/code to Microsoft Entity Framework version 6 and have come across the following problem.

The code-behind defines an enumeration and a POCO object as follows:

```
public enum AssetOwner {
    User = 1,
    Customer = 2,
    Supplier = 3
}

public class Asset {
   public int AssetId { get; set; }
   public string Reference { get; set; }
   public AssetOwner Owner { get; set; }
   ...
};
```

In itself, this is fine, but the SQL table uses, for historical reasons I assume, the enum name rather than its value to store the data.

```
create table [dbo].[Asset] 
(
    [AssetId]     int           not null,
    [Reference]   nvarchar(50)  not null,
    [Owner]       nvarchar(20)  not null
    ...
);
```

So the table might look like this:

```
1, 'asset-1', 'Customer'
2, 'asset-2', 'Supplier'
```

Is there a way (I'm using EF Fluent Configurations) to be able to map the enum's name to the database column?

Comment: Take a look at this link: http://nodogmablog.bryanhogan.net/2014/11/saving-enums-as-strings-with-entity-framework/

Comment: Thanks Fabio, I looked t this and it addresses part of my problem, however it introduces other problems like making sure you only query the database using the string field versions.  I think we might have to consider a more aggressive look at restructering the database.